# How to execute multiple tasks on a specific submodule with gradle?

Tags: gradle, multi-module

I have a multi-module project. Unfortunately I had to place `build.gradle` and `settings.gradle` in other directory(`gradlep/`), rather than root directory, so that I have to use `-p` option.

I found that I can execute multiple tasks on a specific submodule like this.

```
$ gradle -p gradlep/ :long-named-submodule:clean :long-named-submodule:build
```

Is there any way to invoke more concisely?

Comment: What you can do is to define a task in the script that depends on the most often used combinations of tasks and run this aggregate task. That's all that comes to my head.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to **only specify the number of characters needed for Gradle to unambiguously identify your module**. So in your example, if there's no other module that starts with *l* you can do:

`$ gradle -p gradlep/ :l:clean :l:build`

Another option is to **define a new task in your build script that depends on the combinations of tasks you want to run**, as proposed by @Opal in the comments.